# Automated way of import MSSQL tables into SAP B1?

Tags: sapb1, data-import

I am working with SQL Server 2008 & SAP Business One 9.0. I have ten sql server tables which have been imported into the SAP SQL Server database that I would like to add to the SAP Business One client as UDT, UDO & Business objects.

I know I can do this within the SAP business one client, using the Tools -> Customization Tools menu options but this is going to be extremely time consuming, as I will have to create the user-define tables, user-defined fields etc through the interfaces provided etc.

Does anyone know any other way to achieve what I want to do? I was hoping that there would be some SAP tool to import SQL Server tables as UDTs etc.

Comment: Having worked with SAP B1 for more than two years, I'm pretty sure that the only way to add your tables is through the B1 client.

Answer (score 1):

This is the only way that I know of adding user defined tables in the SAP B1 client.
You can add them using something like SQL server management studio, however this is kind of a 'back door' - it's probably more difficult and more time consuming, and on top of that, if you mess it up, SAP won't support you!